# Google Cloud IAP CORS policy is blocking my web app from calling the IAP-protected API

Tags: cors, gcloud, identity-aware-proxy, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I've been having issues with this for too long and I am exhausted...

When my web app is calling my IAP-protected API endpoint, I receive the following error:
`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. What's interesting is that preflight requests and GET requests work.

The failing request is a POST with `content-type: multipart/form-data` (I am uploading a file). I've been thinking it's something wrong on my API, but I see this header in the response: `x-goog-iap-generated-response: true`, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/query-parameters-and-headers-howto#detecting_responses), this response is generated by IAP.

I couldn't find any solution to this problem, I've modified my IAP options:

```
accessSettings:
  corsSettings:
    allowHttpOptions: true
```

and it still doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. If Chrome doesn’t show it, use the Network pane in Firefox devtools to check it. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker Response code is 401, Chrome simply shows CORS Error in the status column.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what have you already tried to solve the issue ?